# Azure and Private non azure based endpoint

Tags: azure, networking, vpn

I have a basic app up and running as a docker container within Azure App Service.

I have an internal endpoint in my company I would like my Azure App Service have access to.

The internal endpoint is a private non internet reachable address - it does not run in azure.

What are my options?

Would prefer not to create a public IP for my private (non azure) endpoint.

Is there some way i can create a some VPN between the app service and private endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to enable networking from app service and set up site to site VPN connection to your on-premise network to allow access your on-premise private endpoint from web app in the Azure app service. See [How regional VNet Integration works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#how-regional-vnet-integration-works) for more details.

[image]

Please note that Azure Virtual Network (VNet) integration for Linux Web App is currently **in Preview**. Customers can use the VNet feature for development and integration testing with your web apps. Please do not use the feature for production purposes.

You could view these related documents for more information:

- https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/app_service_linux_vnet_integration.md
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-app-service-update-free-linux-tier-python-and-java-support-and-more/
- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/41790#issuecomment-571359376